# Initializing a POCO Entity using a constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constructor, poco

I have 2 POCO classes:

(extract of them):

```
public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public Note(int categoryId)
    {
    }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

It's a `1:n` relationship, `Note` has one `Category` and every category has many `Notes`.

I want a constructor on every Entity to initialize all the properties (it's better than using the `Object Initializer`).

But if I use a constructor on `Note`, I don't know how to "bind" the Note with its category.

If I pass the `CategoryId` to the constructor, Category will be `null`. If I pass the `Category` and assign the ID manually, Category will be `null`.

So, is there a way I can initialize a Entity using a constructor and get the category linked to my note aswell?

## EDIT

As you see, I have a constructor on the Note class. My question is: Do I have to pass the `categoryId`, a whole `Category` item? (ReSharper cries if I asign something to a virtual property).

If I pass the `categoryId` to the object, the entities will not be linked.

Comment: you should show your code as well since its not clear what you're doing/expecting

Comment: Updated. Is a simple thing, just want a custom constructor to build my Note class and link the category too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

And what is the point of your effort? It is mostly useless because:

- You still have to provide parameter less constructor because EF needs it
- Your custom constructor will never be used by EF
- If you want to use lazy loading EF needs navigation properties `virtual`
- It is wrong to assign virtual properties from constructor because the virtual code can be overriden in derived class and your constructor can trigger execution of logic in that derived class which hasn't been yet initialized (parent constructor executes first). It is not problem in your exact case but anybody can derive your class and override the `Category` property and it will become a problem. It is simply wrong practice.

Initializers are solution for all your problems so why to bother with parametrized constructor? You should define your priorities. If lazy loading is a must for you, give up with parametrized constructor or live with the fact that `Category` must be configured outside the constructor. If lazy loading is not needed simply remove `virtual` keyword from `Category` and use parametrized constructor as you want.

Comment: You're right, I figured it out when trying to use a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual properties are populated once the entity is attached and saved to the context or returned by the context.

If you really want Category to not be null you should set the id (or navigation property) and apply the changes to the context.

Comment: I read it but I don't know how it applies to my problem. It says how to navigate to related entities, but them are null on my software.

Comment: instead of setting the id to establish relationship, you can just set the navigation property directly and add them as entries to your dbcontext

Comment: Thanks, but I Think is easier to use the Object Initializer :P

Answer (score -2):

If they're POCOs, expose the CategoryId as a readonly property:

```
public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get { return Category == null ? (int?)null : Category.Id; } }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why is that? Just for using a constructor with parameters?